# Val_accuracy staying the same for CNN model to detect brain tumors; I'm thinking that the way I augmented the data and my preprocessing is wrong

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence, data-augmentation

The dataset I am using is https://www.kaggle.com/clarksaben/ct-head-scans

```
def augment_data(image):
    images = [image]
    for i in range(6):
        transform = A.Compose([
        A.Resize(256, 256), 
        A.RandomCrop(224, 224),
        A.OneOf([A.HorizontalFlip(p=1),
                 A.RandomRotate90(p=1),
                 A.VerticalFlip(p=1),
                 A.Blur(),
                 A.RandomBrightnessContrast(p=1)], p = 1),
        A.OneOf([A.MotionBlur(p=1),
                 A.OpticalDistortion(p=1),
                 A.GaussNoise(p=1),
                 A.RandomGamma(p=1),
                 A.CLAHE(p=1)], p=1),
        ])
        transformed_image = transform(image = image)
        images.append(transformed_image['image'])
    return images

def load_data(data):
    paths = ['../input/ct-head-scans/' + x for x in data['ID']]
    images = []
    for path in paths:
        if path.find('gaus') == -1 and path.find('elastic') == -1 and path.find('contrast') == -1 and path.find('gamma') == -1 and path.find('clahe') == -1 and path.find('blur') == -1:
            image = cv2.imread(path, 0)
            image = cv2.bilateralFilter(image, 2, 50, 50)
            augmented = augment_data(image)
            for aImage in augmented:
                img_data = aImage.astype('float32')
        
                img_data = cv2.resize(img_data,(256,256)) / 255
                img_data = img_data.reshape((256,256,1))
                images.append(img_data)
    return images, data['Tumor Present']

def define_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(16, (5, 5), activation = 'relu', input_shape=(256, 256, 1)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(2, 2))
    model.add(Conv2D(16, (5, 5), activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(2, 2))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(2, 2))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(2, 2))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(2, 2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

I have been trying to add new layers and switch the parameters, but nothing seems to work. I believe that the problem could be the way I augmented the data and did the preprocessing, but I'm not sure how to improve upon this. Examples of implementation would be great!

Answer (score 0):

From the [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/clarksaben/ct-head-scans), I can see,

- Control Group has 30 samples
- Necrosis has 22 samples
- Tumor has 31 samples

You have a very low amount of data to train on, so the model is expected to overfit. Even after augmenting and applying dropout layers, the number of data available is too less for the model to learn the underlying features within the images.

One possible way to deal with this is transfer learning. Search (on the internet) for a model trained to classify CT scans and then take the part of the model used to extract the features and use that to perform transfer learning on your dataset. An example of the type of model would be one I did on kaggle: [Brain Tumor Classification (Accuracy~96%)](https://www.kaggle.com/mushfirat/brain-tumor-classification-accuracy-96)

If none of that works, you can train an autoencoder on images of CT scans (you can get it from kaggle), then take the encoder part of the autoencoder to perform transfer learning on your dataset

Answer (score 0):

dataset you have taken contain small amount of data, on which you can apply CNN model so, it expected to overfit and give same accuracy. You can use other algorithm which works good for small amount of dataset, for example: random forest, support vector machine (SVM). and try to make your own model different from kaggle user, if you want to work on this dataset only.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).